# Adding Meta box to thrid-party plugin

Tags: plugin-development, customization

I am about to write a custom plugin that is intended to »extend« a third party plugin, in this case it is: »EME Events made Easy«. I would like to add a Metabox to the »edit event« screen, from within my plugin, so that I do not have to modify the events-plugin code.

How can I do that?

Thanks in ahead,
philipp

**EDIT**

Since my Questions seems to lack some details I am gonna add them now:

I have installed and actived the Plugin: »EME Events made easy«. In the admin section, I can navigate to: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=events-manager&action=edit_event&event_id=<some_id>`

I would like to add a Meta Box to this page, so that I am able to store meta data for each event. There are some hooks, shown [here](http://www.e-dynamics.be/wordpress/?cat=41), I can use to actually store the data.

So far I have written a Plugin, which also activated and running and I am searching for a way to display the metabox, or inject some custom html at a suitable hook.

I have tried:

```
function sw_contact_add_events_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box( 'css-id', 'my-title', 'sw_contact_display_meta', 'events-manager', 'advanced', 'high', array() );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'sw_contact_add_events_meta_boxes' );

function sw_contact_display_meta( $test )
{
    die();
}
```

but the page did not die, so the hook did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Register the metabox for just one post type with `add_meta_boxes_$post_type`:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_event', function()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse_118766_box',
        'Custom Box',
        'wpse_118766_render_box' // function to render the box
    );
});

function wpse_118766_render_box( $post )
{
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Comment: no, the add Meta box hook is not called. I guess that the event-edit-page, or all events are no custom post types. But how can I inject some HTML on this (only on this) page? Is there any other event I can hook in?

Comment: @philipp Add the code registering the events to your question.

Comment: I just used the code you have posted above. (copied and pasted it to my plugin which already activated)

Comment: My code doesn’t register the events, the plugin does. We need that code to help you.

Comment: To confirm what @philipp already suspected, EME does not use custom post types for events so this is going to prevent adding meta boxes using the standard method.